# Attach and handle ng-change from attribute directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-change

We have the "myCustomHandler" **attribute directive**:

```
<input type="text" my-custom-handler ng-model="myModel">
```

The simplified version of the directive looks like this:

```
.directive('myCustomHandler', function () {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.change = function(){
            console.log('model changed');            
        }
    }
}});
```

I need a way to handle the ng-change event in the directive (trigger scope.change() function).

The reason i specifically asked for **ng-change** is that my input is type=text and i need to handle each key. Also, when handling the change, i need the old and new values too(so i prefer avoiding jQuery approaches).

---

I've already considered using $watch for the model, but it won't do it because i need to handle the event only if the model is changed by the user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = { name: 'World' };
  $scope.name = "Felipe";
  $scope.$watch('name',function(o,n){
    console.log(o)
  })
});

app.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      myDirectiveVar: '=',
     //bindAttr: '='
    },
    template: '<div class="some">' +
      '<input ng-model="myDirectiveVar"></div>',
    replace: true,
    //require: 'ngModel',
    link: function($scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      console.debug($scope);
      //var textField = $('input', elem).attr('ng-model', 'myDirectiveVar');
      // $compile(textField)($scope.$parent);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");</script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <my-directive my-directive-var="name"></my-directive>{{name}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It won't do it because i need to handle the change event inside the directive (not in the parent controller). Also, i need an attribute directive not an element directive, so i can add it to existing elements.

Answer (score 0):

[From jquery doc:](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

> For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired
>   immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for
>   the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses
>   focus.

THis means the onChange event will fire when you click out of the input.

```js
function listener() {
  return {
   link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
     elem.bind("change", function() {
       alert('change');
     });
   }
  }
}

angular.module('myApp', []);
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .directive('listener', listener);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <input type="text" listener>
</div>
```

Comment: The reason i specifically asked for ng-change is that my input is type=text and i need to handle each key. Also, when handling the change, i need the old and new values too (in jQuery i need to store the old value in order to achieve this). Thanks!